# Show SQL generated by pending migrations in rails without updating the database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, rake

I'd like to have a way to produce the actual sql (ie: if I pasted into a mysql console, it would work) that will be generated by a rake db:migrate without actually updating the target database.

rake db:migrate:status does a good job of showing which migrations are pending for a given database, but I've yet to find a way to get the actual SQL produced.

Any ideas?

Comment: Following links might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249599/is-it-possible-to-log-sql-queries-on-rake-tasks
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100512/is-it-possible-to-output-the-sql-change-scripts-that-rake-dbmigrate-produces

Comment: thanks, but I think both of those will also send the SQL to the database, right? (though I see now my question wasn't clear enough on that point: updated).

Comment: you could rake db:rollback immediately after

Comment: _rake db:rollback immediately after_ - bad idea if migration does not support rollback, for example in case the migration drops some tables.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to output the SQL change scripts that 'rake db:migrate' produces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100512/is-it-possible-to-output-the-sql-change-scripts-that-rake-dbmigrate-produces)

Comment: @kolen, the questions is different - it's about "without actually updating the target database."

Comment: `rails console --sandbox` and then run migration from console. The SQL will be printed while it is being executed and everything should rollback when you exit the console

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done by monkey-patching the database adapter. This example works for MySQL.

Create a rake task for "fake db:migrate":

```
desc "Prints all SQL to be executed during pending migrations"
task :fake_db_migrate => :environment do

  module ActiveRecord
    module ConnectionAdapters
      class AbstractMysqlAdapter < AbstractAdapter

        alias_method :real_execute, :execute

        def execute(sql, name = nil)
          if sql =~ /^SHOW/ || sql =~ /^SELECT.*FROM.*schema_migrations/ || sql =~ /^SELECT.*information_schema/m
            real_execute(sql, name)
          else
            puts sql
          end
        end

      end
    end
  end

  Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
end
```

The rake task monkey-patches the `execute` method in the connection adapter so that SQL is printed instead of being executed, before actually running the migrations. However, we still have to execute some of the internal SQLs that are used by the `db:migrate` task to get the database schema and to find out which migrations are pending. That's what the `real_execute` call does.

#### Test

Suppose now that and we have a pending migration in `db/migrate/20160211212415_create_some_table.rb`:

```
class CreateSomeTable < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :some_table do |t|
      t.string :string_column, null: false, default: 'ok'
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

$ rake db:migrate:status
...
down    20160211212415  Create some table
```

Now, let's run our fake migrations task:

```
$ rake fake_db_migrate
== 20160211212415 CreateSomeTable: migrating ==================================
-- create_table(:some_table)
CREATE TABLE `some_table` (`id` int(11) auto_increment PRIMARY KEY, `string_column` varchar(255) DEFAULT 'ok' NOT NULL, `created_at` datetime, `updated_at` datetime) ENGINE=InnoDB
   -> 0.0009s
== 20160211212415 CreateSomeTable: migrated (0.0010s) =========================

BEGIN
INSERT INTO `schema_migrations` (`version`) VALUES ('20160211212415')
COMMIT
```

The migrations status has not been changed, i.e. the migration is still pending:

```
$ rake db:migrate:status
...
down    20160211212415  Create some table
```

Tested on rails 4.2.3 with the `mysql2` gem.

Answer (score 23):

Very interesting question! I found this way:

1. Assume your migration placed in file `db/migrate/20160102210050_create_items.rb` and called `CreateItems`
2. Go to Rails console and load migration file:

   ```
   rails c
   require './db/migrate/20160102210050_create_items'
   ```
3. Open transaction, run migration and rollback transaction before commit :)

   ```
   ActiveRecord::Base.connection.transaction do
     CreateItems.new.migrate :up
     raise ActiveRecord::Rollback
   end
   ```

If you want to check SQL on rollback, just call `CreateItems.new.migrate :down` on step 3. SQL will be executed and tested on database, but not committed - so you can verify your migration without affects.

Comment: You can also use `rails c --sandbox` then you don't need any transaction nor any rollback: just use `CreateItems.new.migrate :up` and Rails will automatically rollback when closing the console

Comment: This would only work for RDMBS  that support transactional DDL.

Answer (score 2):

A slightly more low-level function, which can be used for your purpose:

```
# Get SQL query of a migration expression without executing it.
#
# @example
#   schema_statement_to_sql { create_table(:tomatoes) }
#   # => "CREATE TABLE \"tomatoes\" (\"id\" serial primary key) "
def schema_statement_to_sql(&block)
  raise ArgumentError, 'No block given' unless block_given?

  connection = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
  original_execute = connection.method(:execute)
  sql_to_return = ''
  capturing_execute = proc { |sql| sql_to_return = sql }
  connection.define_singleton_method(:execute, &capturing_execute)

  begin
    connection.instance_eval(&block)
  ensure
    connection.define_singleton_method(:execute, &original_execute)
  end

  sql_to_return
end
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do

```
rake db:migrate --dry-run --trace
```

and rake will test the task. Then use one of the methods listed to get the SQL that would be run.

Comment: I'm unclear how this is an accepted answer. What methods are you talking about? Nothing in the `--dry-run` or `--trace` indicates another task to run that prints SQL.